# Are there any gcc flags that will dump named objects before compilation?

Tags: gcc

Consider the simple C file:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    return x;
}
```

I'd like to extract a few things:

1. Ideally, all named things and their type.  So I should get something like: `int, main, function` and `int x variable` or something like that
2. Extra points if the variable initialization is there as well

I'm sure that gcc does this internally, since that's an important compilation step, but I'm not sure if I can extract this information.

I'm also not strictly tied to gcc, so if another compiler does this I can consider it, but gcc is preferred.

Comment: Clang has an API to query and change almost every aspect of compiled code. Gcc, not so much.

Comment: I'm not aware of a gcc feature which does that. (And it would probably happen *after* compilation ;-) ). But a development environment usually comes with tools which inspect object files and provide information about it, in particular about all "named objects", i.e. symbols. In gcc environments these are [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) and [nm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm). The tools and their output will probably be a bit more unwieldy than you'd like at first, but they are versatile.